# Jenkins Shell Script variable assignment fails when parsing curl response

Tags: shell, parsing, jenkins

i have a curl statement that i run in a shell script in the Jenkins Execute Shell Script plugin, that will return a json object:    {"request_id":"52d4520c09228dc810000096"}.

Curl statement runs fine and returns the proper response json object.

I need to parse this object and get the value back to use as a parameter for the next Jenkins Job. Currently using tr and cut to parse the json response.

When i try this code it fails:

```
    curl -s -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -d "{my parameters}" http://my_http_post_url | tr -d '{}"' | cut -f 2 -d ':' - > ${response_id};
```

Fails with:

```
    cannot create : Directory nonexistent
    + cut -f 2 -d : -
    + curl -s -X POST -H Accept:application/json -d {my params} http://my_http_post_url
    tr: write error: Broken pipe
    Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Also tried this:

```
    ${response_id}=$(curl -s -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -d "{my parameters}" http://my_http_post_url | tr -d '{}"' | cut -f 2 -d ':');
```

Fails with (note: 52d4520c09228dc810000096 is the proper response id):

```
    + cut -f 2 -d :
    + curl -s -X POST -H Accept:application/json -d {my params} http://my_http_post_url
    + tr -d {}"
    + = 52d4520c09228dc810000096
    /tmp/hudson3217430586060280102.sh: 2: /tmp/hudson3217430586060280102.sh: = 52d4520c09228dc810000096: not found
    Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell syntax is different from Perl. In shell you put a dollar sign in front of a variable  only when you refer to the variable and want the shell to expand it with it's value. You do not use the dollar sign when assigning the variable.

Your 2nd try seems best:

```
response_id=$(curl -s -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -d "{my parameters}" http://my_http_post_url | tr -d '{}"' | cut -f 2 -d ':')
```

Also, semicolon at the end is not needed.

Additionally, I would recommend you use a specialized tool for parsing JSON. If you use tr, awk and such, you assume certain line-based formatting in your input but JSON can be formatted in many ways and still be valid JSON. Use a tool such as jq (http://stedolan.github.io/jq/). Then you could just do:

```
response_id=$(curl -s -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -d "{my parameters}" http://my_http_post_url | jq -r .request_id)
```

I usually use the -f curl option. I like to know when server sent back something else than 200 OK.

Comment: So i got the Environment Inject Plugin Installed so i could save the values from a shell script which is in the scope of the current Job and save it in such a way that i could pass its value to the next job on the chain as a parameter: https://wiki.jenkins-   
ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin.

Comment: request_id=$(curl -s -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -d {myparams} http://myurl | jq -r .request_id);   
echo id=$request_id > propsfile;
echo Token received from Kitchen: $propsfile;

Comment: As far as I know, the EnvInject plugin cannot be used to pass a variable from one job to another. The https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin seems to be the correct tool for this job. Write the request_id to a properties file and configure the plugin to pass variables from the properties file as parameters to the triggered job (which must be configured to have the expect those parameters, of course.)

Comment: Correct.  I have that plugin for my second job and it is able to reference the EnvInject Properties file.  Apparently the EnvInject prop file is appended to the current environment variables so it can be references as though i'm passing the environment variables to the next job.